# Refreshcontrol in scrollview is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have a scrollable content in my view. I want to add pull to refresh in it. I try to add but action is not triggered.

I tried many couple of ways & re-search also but none of it worked for me. I have iOS 10 as minimum deployment target.

Try1:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.scl_view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
scl_view.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Try2:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.scl_view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
scl_view.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

//MARK:- Refresh control

```
@objc func pullToRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    // Update your conntent here
    self.setupData()
    //refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: did you able to find any solution? 
I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

select your tablviewcontroller
goto inspector
find refreshing select enabled
goto document outline and select refresh control
control drag or right click(hold) drag to your controller file and call function on it to refresh data

it is not available on tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    // Add Refresh Control to collection View
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }

    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.72, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)
    // Configure Refresh Control
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fetchData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}


@objc private func fetchData(_ sender: Any) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Fuction which you want to call
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }
}
```